# Add ENum Attribute to existing table using Alter

Tags: oracle, alter-table, enum

I am using oracle XE and trying to add a attribute that restricts to only three  available value 'Small','Medium','large' to an existing table using Alter Table and Enum.

Tried doing,

```
ALTER TABLE TRUCK ADD TTYPE ENUM('SMALL','MEDIUM','LARGE');
```

but gets invalid option

```
ALTER TABLE TRUCK ADD TTYPE ENUM('SMALL','MEDIUM','LARGE');
                                 *
```

where the error highlights after ENUM.

I think I am having syntax error. Please help to resolve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
ALTER TABLE TRUCK 
    ADD (ttype VARCHAR2(6) 
    CONSTRAINT con_type 
    CHECK (ttype in('SMALL','MEDIUM','LARGE'))
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `ENUM` datatype in Oracle. You can use a foreign key constraint to a reference table (with 3 rows) or a `CHECK` constraint instead:

```
ALTER TABLE truck 
  ADD ttype VARCHAR(6),
  ADD CONSTRAINT ttype_check
    CHECK (ttype IN ('SMALL','MEDIUM','LARGE')) ;
```